# Get status message of MySQL query (including execution time) with JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jdbc

Suppose that I am implementing a query in MySQL say

```
Create Database newdb;
```

then the database responds the result

```
database created in 0.05 sec
```

Now my question is how to get this message in a Java program using JDBC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code works for me

```java
try (Statement s = conn.createStatement()) {
    s.execute("SET PROFILING=1;");
    s.execute("CREATE DATABASE newdb;");
    try (ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SHOW PROFILES;")) {
        rs.next();
        System.out.printf(
                "     Statement: %s%nExecution time: %f seconds.%n", 
                rs.getString("Query"), 
                rs.getDouble("Duration"));
    }
    s.execute("SET PROFILING=0;");
}
```

The console output is

```
     Statement: CREATE DATABASE newdb
Execution time: 0.002014 seconds.
```

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do that. Not at least with JDBC. All you can do is -

```
Class.forName(jdbcDriver);
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/?user=root&password=");
Statement statement = connection .createStatement();
int result = statement.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS" + dbName)
```

and you will get `result` as 0.

Note that when the return value for executeUpdate is 0, it can mean one of two things:

- The statement executed was an update statement that affected zero rows.
- The statement executed was a DDL statement.

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)